BunDB read nested relation row
I want to read Book filtered by author's grad school name and get all details for those books.
I've structs as Book, Author, Publisher and School. Relations for the same are defined in structs itself
type Book struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:book"`

    AuthorID        uint32    `bun:"author_id"`
    PublisherID     uint32    `bun:"publisher_id"`
    
    Author    *Author              `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:author_id=id"`
    Publisher *Publisher           `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:publisher_id=id"`
}

type Author struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:author"`

    ID uint32 `bun:"id,pk"`
    Name      string    `bun:"name"`

    HighSchoolID uint32    `bun:"grad_school_id"`
    HighSchoo   *School `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:grad_school_id=id"`

    GradSchoolID uint32    `bun:"grad_school_id"`
    GradSchool   *School `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:grad_school_id=id"`
}

type Publisher struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:publisher"`

    ID        uint32    `bun:"id,pk"`
    Name      string    `bun:"name"`
}

type School struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:school"`

    ID        uint32    `bun:"id,pk"`
    Name      string    `bun:"name"`
}

I've tried with following query but this fails on nested where clause
repo.db.
Reader().
NewSelect().
Model(&Book{}).
Relation("Author").
Relation("Publisher").
Relation("Author.HighSchool").
Relation("Author.GradSchool").
Where("grad_school.name = ?", "grad_school_name").
Scan(ctx)


Is this really related to the SQL language? There's no SQL above, do you expect an SQL answer?

This is on bun orm.
Ref: https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/

I expect fields to be placed in place on where clause as it is throwing error currently.

You should enable debug mode that prints bun queries to stdout and see what alias is assigned to nested relation.
I think bun adds double underscore between relations so in your case it might be:
Relation("Author.GradSchool"). // this becomes author__grad_school in sql
Where("author__grad_school.name = ?", "grad_school_name").

but query debugging will show you the correct name.
